# Restrict access to custom post type and filter from every query

Tags: filters, query, user-access, content-restriction

I created a custom post type `topic` which is just for internal use. I managed to assign the correct capabilities so that users of certain roles can edit/publish/delete posts.

Now I want to redirect every request to a single `topic` or a `topic` archive to the login screen (if not logged) respectively a 404 page (if has not certain roles). Furthermore I want to hook into `pre_get_posts` to exclude my CPT from any other query (if not logged in or wrong role) so it will not appear on the home page for example.

I have exclusively assigned a custom taxonomy to that custom post type. So of course I also want to redirect these taxonomy term archives to a 404 or login screen.

This is my permalink structure:

```
/forum/%topic_type%/%topic%  – Single topic post
/forum/%topic_type%          – List all topic posts with term X
/forum                       – List all topic posts
```

Every topic has a topic_type term.

#### Bonus question

I also want to filter the nav menu items linking to an object with CPT.

---

### My Approach

```
/**
 * Check capabilities
 */
function has_forum_capabilities() {
    return current_user_can('bulletin_user')
           || current_user_can('organizer')
           || current_user_can('administrator');
}

/**
 * Redirect to home url or to login url
 */
function do_redirect() {
    $redirect_uri = home_url();

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

        $redirect_uri = wp_login_url( home_url( add_query_arg( NULL, NULL ) ) );

    }

    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_uri, 302 );
    exit();
}

/**
 * Restrict access to non-forum users
 */
function filter_query( $query ) {

    if (is_admin()) {
        return $query;
    }
    if (  has_forum_capabilities() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    $post_types = (array) $query->get( 'post_type' );

    if (false !== ($key = array_search('topic', $post_types))) {

        unset($post_types[$key]);

        if (empty($post_types)) {

            if ($query->is_main_query()) {
                do_redirect();
            } else {
                $query->set( 'post_type', '' );
                $query->is_404 = 1;
            }

        } else {
            $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
        }

    }

    if ($query->get('topic_type', false)) {
        if ($query->is_main_query()) {
            do_redirect();
        } else {
            unset($query->topic_type);
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_query', 99999 );
```

#### Custom Post Types and Taxonomies

I am using [Joe Grainger's WP Custom Post Type Class](https://github.com/jjgrainger/wp-custom-post-type-class) to register my custom post types and taxonomies but it is basically the same. I excluded irrelevant arguments in this example code.

```
$topic = new CPT(
    [
        'post_type_name'    => 'topic'
    ],
    [
        'taxonomies'            => [ 'topic_type' ],
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'has_archive'           => 'forum',     
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => [
                                     'slug'         => __('forum/%topic_type%/%post_id%'),
                                     'with_front'   => false,
                                     'pages'        => true,
                                     'feeds'        => true,
                                   ],
        'capability_type'       => 'topic',
        'map_meta_cap'          => true,
        'capabilities'          => [
                                     'read_post'        => 'edit_topic'
                                   ],
    ]
);

$topic->register_taxonomy(
    [
        'taxonomy_name' =>  'topic_type'
    ],
    [
        'rewrite'       =>  [
                              'slug'            =>  'forum',
                              'with_front'  =>  false,
                              'hierarchical'    =>  true,
                              'ep_mask'     =>  'EP_NONE',
                            ],
        'capabilities'  =>  [
                              'manage_terms'    => 'manage_topic_types',
                              'edit_terms'      => 'manage_topic_types',
                              'delete_terms'    => 'manage_topic_types',
                              'assign_terms'    => 'edit_topics',
                            ]
    ]
);
```

#### Mapping the meta capabilities

To assign the primitive capabilities to user roles I am using the [Justin Tadlock's Members Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/). The following works but I am not quite sure if this is correct.

```
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'map_meta_capabilities', 10, 4 );
function map_meta_capabilities( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {

    /* If editing, deleting, or reading a topic, get the post and post type object. */
    if ( 'edit_post' == $cap || 'delete_post' == $cap || 'read_post' == $cap ) {
        $post = get_post( $args[0] );
        $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
        /* Set an empty array for the caps. */
        $caps = array();
    }

    /* If editing a topic, assign the required capability. */
    if ( 'edit_post' == $cap ) {
        if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_posts;
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_others_posts;
    }
    /* If deleting a topic, assign the required capability. */
    elseif ( 'delete_post' == $cap ) {
        if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_posts;
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_others_posts;
    }
    /* If reading a private topic, assign the required capability. */
    elseif ( 'read_post' == $cap ) {
        if ( 'private' != $post->post_status )
            $caps[] = 'read';
        elseif ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = 'read';
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->read_private_posts;
    }
    /* Return the capabilities required by the user. */
    return $caps;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you used to register the custom post type?

Comment: I added some more code examples.